# XSLT function for escaping quotes?

Tags: xslt, escaping

I have some XSLT that gets an attribute and sends it as part of the URL to a php $_GET variable. It looks like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">search.php?subject="<xsl:value-of select="@level1"/>"</xsl:attribute>
```

It works with most values of @level1. For instance,  if the value is `foo`, I get this url:

```
search.php?subject="foo"
```

The problem is, when that value of `@level1` contains a quotation mark, like `"bar" etc etc` it doesn't work. I get this:

```
search.php?subject=""bar" etc etc"
```

Which of course returns an empty `subject`. If I add backslashes, suddenly it works. For instance, if I edit the URL to read:

```
search.php?subject="\"bar\" etc etc"
```

then `$_GET['subject]=="bar" etc etc`! So how can I get XSL to add backslashes to escape these rogue quotation marks? I tried

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">search.php?subject="<xsl:value-of select='replace(@level1,",\")'/>"</xsl:attribute>
```

and I tried

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">search.php?subject="<xsl:value-of select="replace(@level1,&quot;,\&quot;"/>"</xsl:attribute>
```

But nothing seems to work yet.

Answer (score 2):

In **XSLT 2.0** use the `replace()` function.

In **XSLT 1.0** use the recursive `exslt:replace` template which you can find at http://www.exslt.org

(And either way, when you ask questions about XSLT, tell us which version you are using).